# can you say "he is in a lively chat with her"

Tags: writing-style, phrase-usage, contemporary-english

My question is about style. Does it sound natural if you say that someone "is in a lively chat/conversation with someone" or is it better to say "he is ENGAGED in a lively chat with her"?

Comment: We can say _in conversation_ (though not _in chat_), but if you add an adjective it needs to be _engaged in a lively conversation_.

Comment: @KateBunting

Thanks. So it's either:
_He is in conversation with her._
OR
_He is engaged in a lively conversation/chat with her._
?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: *He is in a lively chat with her* sounds perfectly fine to me, even though I would call it informal language.

Answer (score 1):

"He is engaged in a lively chat with her" is technically correct, but the usual way to say this would be "he is *having* a lively chat with her".